# Changing font size of value in specific valueBox (flexdashboard)

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with a bunch of valueBoxes. However some have values that are very long strings, and as such overflow the page and generally just look ugly. I want to be able to dynamically change the value font-size of specific valueBoxes when the character length of the value exceeds a certain limit.

I know I can globally change the font-size with css like so:

```
.value-box .value {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But I don't want to change the value font-size for every valueBox, just specific valueBoxes.

I've also tried using the `tags` function from `shiny` to edit the font-size directly:

```
### Test Heading
flexdashboard::valueBox(
  value = shiny::tags$p("This is a very long string", style = "font-size: 20px;"),
  caption = "Test Caption"
)
```

But that doesn't seem to do change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, assign your long strings to values, then use `inline R code` to call the value inside the valueBox.

````
---
title: "Super long string"
author: ""
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
    vertical_layout: fill
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(flexdashboard)
value = 'this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string'
```

Column {data-width=350}
-------------------------------------
### ```r value```

```{r}
valueBox("Valuebox", icon = "fa-pencil", href="#details")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you have a good point! It is probably not the right use of value boxes if I'm in situations where I want to display long strings, but alas it is a format I can't change. Also, as you mention, I do actually have quite a lot of value boxes displayed and so having the text displayed under the box would not quite work I think.

Comment: actually just updated my answer after revision.

Comment: I'm not quite following, I know how to display the value, but I want to be able to dynamically change the font size of specific value boxes, without having to globally change the font size of every value box